# Kendo Grid customized java script function to PDf download is not working on IOS(IPAD and IPhone) based devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI grid pdf export functionality in my Asp.Net mvc based project using the same business logic as shown in the below url.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/pdf-export

The issue I am facing here is in the above link pdf export/download does not work on IOS operating system based devices like IPhone and IPAD while the same works on windows, Android and MAC OS.

My efforts on this:
1. I have tried and tested the PDF download issue on MAC book air(MAC OS) laptop and pdf download looks good to me. After downloading I can see the pdf(all pages) in MAC book. 
2. For IPAD when tested the same I found that IPAD is showing only first page of pdf in Image(png) format once click on pdf download button. Also the pdf is opening in the same window of my report UI. I mean pdf is not downloading in IPAD.

My query here is why the same piece of code works fine in MACBook(MAC OS) and why not in IPAD(IOS)?

My current Code snippet:

Javascript function:

```
function SavePdf() {           
            kendo.drawing.drawDOM("#divStoreRoyaltyReportPrint", {               
                paperSize: [1170, 1620],
                margin: { left: "1cm", top: "0.5mm", right: "1cm", bottom: "0.9cm" },              
                template: $("#divFooterTable").html(),
                repeatHeaders: true,
                landscape: false,
                multiPage: true
            }).then(function (group) {
                root.options.set("pdf");
                kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "StoreRoyalty.pdf",'@Url.Action("Save", "Home")');               
            });
        }
```

MVC Controller side code

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Save(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
            {
                var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

                return File(fileContents, contentType, fileName);
            }
```

Can anyone help here to rectify this issue.

Comment: What the kendo-grid does is generating the PDF client side, and when the client doesn't implement the file API, it used the server side proxy (actually it just bounces the incoming filedata back to the client). Did you try setting a breakpoint in the Save method and inspect the bytes, or write the file to disk on the server? That will rule out a bug in the PDF creation on the iPad.

Comment: During my debug I found that in kendo scripts(Kendo.all.js / Kendo.all.min.js) js file there is one java-script function called when pdf export button is clicked. In this function there is one condition which says that if kendo does not support safari browser then it will return the blob(Image) in return.    This is the below function of kendo js file which is called:

Comment: function o(t, n, o, a) {
            window.Blob && !e.support.browser.safari && 0 ? r(t, function(t) {
                e.saveAs({
                    dataURI: t,
                    fileName: n
                }), a && a(t)
            }) : i(t, function(t) {
                e.saveAs({
                    dataURI: t,
                    fileName: n,
                    proxyURL: o
                }), a && a(t)
            })
        }